# Wrap text with both spaces and no spaces

Tags: longtable, wrap

Trying to wrap text using `longtable` combined with `seqsplit` but it won't format correctly for something like 
`thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample with a space` because `seqsplit` removes all spaces

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[left=65pt,top=28pt,right=65pt,bottom=65pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{50pt} p{360pt} p{50pt}}

& \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample with a space} & test \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Howsabout adding a backslash before `seqsplit`?

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo. seqsplit removes spaces so i assume i need to use a different package

Comment: I don't know the `seqsplit` package, but the way you use it with non-existing _very_ long strings of letters, how is it supposed to work in combination with LaTeX's hyphenation algorithm.

Comment: If you use control spaces `\ ` or ties `~`, they're not removed. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the spaces, use a control space `\` or a tie `~` between the words:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=65pt,top=28pt,right=65pt,bottom=65pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable
\usepackage{seqsplit}% http://ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{50pt} p{360pt} p{50pt}}
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample with a space} & test1 \\
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample\ with\ a\ space} & test2 \\
  & \seqsplit{thisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexamplethisisareallylongexample~with~a~space} & test3 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The first row shows the original, the second uses a control space `\` while the third row uses a tie `~` to preserve the spacing.

Comment: Awesome thanks, it was a little tricky because it's being generated through php but $string = str_replace(" ","~",$string), did the trick